# What are such functions called in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
(function createTaskRecord() {
    // with some details
}())  // <--- whats the use of parentheses after the } ?
```

I am new to Javascript and wish to understand what are functions with `()` in the end called ? Why are they used and when ?

Comment: While it looks very strange indeed, this is now a very common practice in JS. Note that the identifier `createTaskRecord` is pointless here, except if the function has to call itself recursively, or for the mere purpose of code explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is called immediate execution. This will evaluate your function immediately.

Actually there is a more formal name for functions that are defined with this way: IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) has a great article about them:

> An immediately-invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced
>   "iffy") is a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope
>   using JavaScript's function scoping. Immediately-invoked function
>   expressions **can be used to avoid variable hoisting from within blocks**,
>   **protect against polluting the global environment** and simultaneously
>   **allow public access to methods while retaining privacy for variables**
>   **defined within the function**. This pattern has been referred to as a
>   self-executing anonymous function, but Ben Alman introduced the term
>   IIFE as a more semantically accurate term for the pattern, shortly
>   after its discussion arose on comp.lang.javascript.